# Front end technology / framework

Tags: spring, hibernate, frontend

I am using Spring MVC and Hibernate for a project. I am little confused about which technology to use in front end part(in jsp part), to get better look and fill as well which is easy to adopt.

Thanks in advance, :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest [GWT with Spring and Hibernate](http://prayag-waves.blogspot.com/2013/04/web-technology-stack-i-prefer-on-jvm.html) if that fits your requirements. GWT has great [widgets](http://ongwt.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/com.google.gwt.sample.showcase.Showcase/Showcase.html#CwBasicText) and a vibrant community. There's [GWTP](https://code.google.com/p/gwt-platform/wiki/GettingStarted?tm=6), a nice MVP framework for GWT.

[image: JVM Stack]

For other options, go through [Matt Raible's Java frameworks comparison](http://www.slideshare.net/mraible/comparing-jvm-web-frameworks). Spend 2/3 days to pick one that fits your requirements the best.